# Why does Rashi call tzeirei and segol "kamatz katan" and "patach katan"

Tags: names, grammar-dikduk, rashi, vowels-nekudot

Rashi often refers to tzeirei as "kamatz katan" and segol as "patach katan".  Why?  In what sense are they smaller versions of kamatz and patach?

I understand that kamatz and tzeirei are תנועות גדולות, while patach and segol are תנועות קטנות, which has some consequences for sheva na and dageshim.  Rashi's classification is going in a different direction.  Does it also have grammatical consequences?

```
             Tenuah gedola       Tenuah ketana
Rashi big    Kamatz              Patach
Rashi small  Tzeirei             Segol
```

Comment: What do you mean "why"? Those are the names he had. People have different names for things sometimes.

Comment: https://books.google.co.il/books?id=RyHpAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA9

Comment: @DoubleAA of course he didn't make them up, I mean in what sense are they smaller versions of kamatz and patach

Comment: Perhaps we should examine how Rashi pronounced Hebrew; then, we can analyze and see what he might refer to these vowels accordingly. Does anyone know how Hebrew was pronounced in France/Germany during the Crusades?

Comment: @ezra This topic is is discussed in this book: [מסורת הלשון של הרמב"ם לפי האוטוגרף של פירושו למשנה תורת ההגה ומערכת הפועל](http://www.magnespress.co.il/Book/%D7%A2%D7%93%D7%94+%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9F.aspx?&code=45-351071&)

Comment: See also the Bahur's comments on this in [Massoret ham-Massoret](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=ULkOAAAAYAAJ&pg=PP186#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: I wonder if by קטן Rashi means closer (i.e. that the space between the tongue and the roof of the mouth is smaller). This seems to be consistent with all of the names in Argon's first link, and it makes some sense with the name פתח קטן ("small open" as opposed to the fully open פתח)

Comment: By the way, in Babylonian Niqqud, patach and segol had the same symboi. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_vocalization